# Render quicktabs in view template file

Tags: views, blocks

I am using quicktabs module for grouping three view blocks as a single block.
Everthing is working fine with quicktabs . But according to my design , i Have to render tabs created by quicktabs in my views template file .

How can i achieve that.

Please Help !

Answer (score 2):

You can reder quick tabs using [quicktabs_build_quicktabs](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!quicktabs!quicktabs.module/function/quicktabs_build_quicktabs/7) function..

> Constructs a Quicktabs instance.
>
> This function can be called by other modules to programmatically build
>   a quicktabs instance.

```
<?php
   $quicktabs = quicktabs_build_quicktabs('recruitment_quicktabs'); // use your qt name here
   print render($quicktabs);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Anil .. I have to render tabs in my view template file .I am not using any custom module for this.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716